# What is the correct syntax for an IF statement in a FOR loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to populate an array with the combined values of two other arrays and am trying to use a for loop to do so.

```
var filterTables = ["1","2","3"]
var filterValues = ["Egypt",,"Ghana"]

for (i = 0; i < filterValues.length ; i++) {        
  if (filterValues[i]) { 
    for (i = 0; i < filterValues.length ; i++) {
      var filter = '{field: '+filterTables[i]+',value:'+filterValues[i]+',operator:"="},'
      filterArray.filters.push(filter)       
      if (i===3) {
         '{field: "'+filterTables[i]+'",value:"'+filterValues[i]+'",operator:"="}'
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

But the FOR loop isn't executing at all and I think it is because of the first IF statement that checks if there is a value in the current [i] position. Is it being used correctly? Do I need an IF statement outside of the FOR loop?

This is the desired result:

```
var filter = '{field: '1',value:'Egypt',operator:"="}'
var filter = '{field: '3',value:'Ghana',operator:"="}'
```

Comment: You're using the variable `i` in both loops . That is a mistake.

Comment: The code in `if (i===3)` isn't assigning the variable.

Comment: Wait, why not use array.map?

Comment: BTW, why aren't you using `JSON.stringify()` instead of constructing these strings by hand?

Comment: You don't need two for loops to obtain your desired result

Comment: Right, nested loops are for getting all combinations from the two arrays. If you want to combine them in parallel, you just use one loop and use the index for both arrays.

Comment: `i === 3` will never be true with those arrays. Why do you need to do something extra in that case, anyway?

Comment: @MarcoDalZovo Post an answer showing how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few issues here:

1- What are the variables `filterArray` and `filterArray.filters`? Are they defined in your code? I assume they are not, because once I added a declaration, the loop executed as expected.

2- As pointed out by many comments, you don't need nested loops to reach the desired result (plus you are using the same counter `i` in both loops, which will definitely cause problems).

You can use one loop, and at each iteration read `filterTables[i]`, `filterValues[i]`, and fill an object accordingly.

And on a side note, why not use `JSON.stringify` to build your JSON string?

```js
var filterTables = ["1","2","3"];
var filterValues = ["Egypt",,"Ghana"];
var filterArray = {'filters': []}; //added variable declaration for the object `filterArray` and its property `filters`

for(var i = 0; i < filterValues.length; i++) {
  if(filterValues[i]) {
    var filter = JSON.stringify({
      field: filterTables[i], //I assume here you could just use i+1
      value: filterValues[i],
      operator: '='
    });
    
    filterArray.filters.push(filter);
  }
}

console.log(filterArray.filters);
```

Comment: Thanks. Works well.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the result you asked, that is the logic you should implement:

```js
// Why did you call Array an Object?
// That sounds better
let filterObject = {
  filters: []
};
let filterTables = ['1','2','3'];
let filterValues = ['Egypt',,'Ghana'];

// Here you need only one for loop
// Each cycle, you increment i by 1 and access next element in filterValues array
for(let i = 0; i < filterValues.length; i++) {
  let value = filterValues[i];
  if(!value) continue; // If the value does not exist, you can continue and avoid useless logic
  
  // Here you can access current table element (from filterTables array) using i
  let table = filterTables[i];
  
  // Don't create an object using string
  // Create it as object (yeah, seems like crazy :D) instead
  let filter = {
    field: table,
    value: value,
    operator: '='
  };
  
  filterObject.filters.push(filter);
}

console.log(filterObject);
```

Please note that if you need a JSON formatted object, you can call directly the stringify method on the **filter** object, like this:

```
JSON.stringify(filter);
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Pointy you have used 'i' in both loops, that's a mistake. 
However there is a better way to achieve what you are trying. ES6 to the rescue !

Try this:
(I have tested it is working fine)

```
let filterArray = { filters: [] };
            var filterTables = ["1", "2", "3"];
            var filterValues = ["Egypt", , "Ghana"];

            let result = filterValues.map(function (x, i) {
                if (x) {
                return { "field": filterTables[i] , "value": x }
                }
            })

            console.log(result)
```

Comment: Neat solution. But based on the OP's expected output, I believe `field` should be set to `i + 1` instead if `i`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @AnisR. I've edited my answer.

Comment: That is not quite right. You can't assume that field will be anumber forever... In my opinion is better to use the value in the array

Comment: Yes I see your point @MarcoDalZovo , my bad. Edited !